# Weird hibernate reference error, however it is not added as a library

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class StartUp
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$7.run(LauncherImpl.java:791)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    at gui.GraphicApplication.<init>(GraphicApplication.java:28)
    at StartUp.<init>(StartUp.java:26)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application StartUp
```

However i am not even using the Hibernate library, i am using JPA, i tried searching for "Session", "hibernate" and other strings but i can't find any of those and yet it is throwing this error.

These are the libraries i am currently using:

[image: libraries]

I was using hibernate before but i had to use JPA, so i removed everything that had to do with Hibernate.

The stacktrace is referencing to some of my files but nothing on those lines has anything to do with database management.

Comment: lAppointmentGroupMap.put("group02", new Agenda.AppointmentGroupImpl().withStyleClass("group2")); neither of those classes are even persistable and do not use hibernate in any way

Comment: A stack trace doesn't lie; NoClassDefFoundError means that that line is bringing in a requirement for Hibernate Session. It may be in a dep of those classes, or a dep of a dep. But it is being pulled in from there.

Comment: Well, i couldnt find anything, i recreated the project with the same source files and everything seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Hibernate JAR's to the lib directory of your server by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Well the stack trace says clear enough that "gui.GraphicApplication.(GraphicApplication.java:28)" is referencing it, so look at that and fix it?